# shared memory questions - shm_open and msync

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, mmap

### Background:

Currently my application has a global array (which gets allocated using malloc) and is updated by almost all the functions in the application.

The application also has a signal handler function that writes this array content to a file on disk upon receiving a signal.

### Sample Code:

app.c

```
static int *list;

void function_1() {
    list[0]++;
}
void function_2() {
    list[1]++;
}
void function_3() {
    list[2]++;
}

int main () {
    get_storage (&list, 4);
    signal(SIGINT, handle_sigint);
    
    list[3]++;

    function_1();
    function_2();
    function_3();
}

void handle_sigint (int sig) 
{ 
    // Write the array List to file 
}
```

storage.c

```
void get_storage (int **list, int len) {
   
   int total_size = (len + 1) * sizeof(int);

   int *arr =  (int *) malloc (total_size);
   memset (addr, 0, total_size);

   arr[0] = len;
   *list = (arr + 1);

}
```

### Use-Case:

I am working on removing the signal handler function by

- using shared memory/mmap to allocate the array (backed by the file) - so that I always have the file with the latest content of the array at any point when the application is running.

### Sample Code:

app.c:

```
static int *list;

void function_1() {
    list[0]++;
}
void function_2() {
    list[1]++;
}
void function_3() {
    list[2]++;
}

int main () {
    get_storage (&list, 4);
    list[3]++;

    function_1();
    function_2();
    function_3();
}
```

storage.c

```
void get_storage (int **list, int len) {

   char shm_name [255] = {0};
   snprintf (shm_name, 255, "list_%d_file.dat", (int)getpid());
   int total_size = (len + 1) * sizeof(int);

   int shm_fd = shm_open (shm_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
   ftruncate(shm_fd, total_size);
   void *addr = mmap(0, total_size, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
   memset (addr, 0, total_size);

   int *arr =  (int *)addr;
   arr[0] = len;
   *list = (arr + 1);

}
```

### Questions:

1. Is it recommended to use:

- shm_open() - which creates the file in /dev/shm OR
- open() - which can create file in any directory.

/dev/shm has limited space and is not retained up-on the system reload.

What are the overheads of using a file in any directory vs a file in /dev/shm opened via shm_open()?

2. When should i use msync?

- Should it be done after every time the array is updated ? if so, then it seems like the malloc and signal handler approach would be better.

I see the data is updated at real time in my experiment without msync.
What are the implications of not using msync? I am using Linux.

Comment: Hi -- just a thought.  This question might be improved by sharing the code so the community can see *how* you intend to use these functions -- it might make a difference?  Not sure, but I notice that when there are so few responses in the comments like this, it usually means needed info is missing, and community is not sure how to help.   If you add code and still no responses, then I apologize in advance.

Comment: Sure, added sample code. Lets see.

Comment: On Linux, the kernel tracks dirty pages and flushes them to storage, so that you don't have to. However, it may take some time for the changes to get written. So if your program requires that the content is fully flushed at a specific point, you need to call `msync` with `MS_SYNC` flag (which you cannot do from a signal handler, because this function is not signal-safe).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: When other processes (including cp)  read the file - will those processes  also not access from the cache first, so that the changes which are not yet flushed should be available right?